# Ошибка несоответствия типов при создании фрагмента

Tags: java, android

Делаю все, как на уроке https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XbhtAlHJeGw.
Проблема в том, что не создаётся папка `layout` с фрагментами. 
Фрагменты хранятся в папке с `MainActivity`, поэтому при написании `fragment = new FragmentOne()`, IDE подчёркивает строку красным и пишет, что происходит несоответствие типов.
Подскажите, как исправить?

Comment: Проблема скорее всего не в папке. Покажите объявление переменной `fragment` и класса `FragmentOne()` - наверное у вас последний просто не фрагмент.

Comment: Либо напутали с импортами. Где-то фрагменты из сдк, где-то из саппорт библиотеки.